# I need help finding a word for essay title

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

I am writing as essay on Women's stereotypes and I cannot find a word to go in my title. The essay must be in a letter format. I want my title to be:

> Dear Society: Stop ___________-ing Women.

I would like a word other than *stereotyping*. I have already tried *conventionalizing*, but it just doesn't seem right (Is that even a word?).

Answer (score 1):

***Labelling***, or ***categorizing***, might do the trick.

*Label* -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/label)

> (verb) 1.1 Assign to a category, especially inaccurately or restrictively